# How to prevent disappearing ANT console while calling from .bat file?

Tags: batch-file, ant, build

Hi I have created simple build.bat file which is as below :

```
    @echo off
    ant -buildfile build-rj-projects.xml
    pause
```

and my build-rj-projects.xml build file is as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <project name="RJ Build Projects" default="info">

   <target name="info">
      <echo>Hello World - Welcome to Apache Ant!</echo>
   </target>

</project>
```

Now when I double click on build.bat file it executes target of build-rj-projects.xml file, but suddenly console disappears ! :( .I have tried putting another target

```
<sleep seconds="10"/>
```

in build-rj-projects.xml file but it sleeps for 10 seconds for every target in build-rj-projects.xml file.Any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ant` is usually a batch file. When you invoke a batch file from another batch file, the execution flow is transfered to the called one and does not return to the caller. In your case, that means the `pause` command is not executed because your batch file ends when `ant` is invoked. You need to change your calling line to

```
call ant -buildfile build-rj-projects.xml
```

using the `call` command, when the called batch file ends, the execution flow returns to the caller.